# How to modify the python code using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, webdriver

All details are printed but problem is that in this I use many `for` loops. How to overcome this problem and deal with `for` loop? I tried to get rid of many `for` loops but I failed.
Here is my link: https://www.foodpanda.pk/restaurants/new?lat=24.9414896&lng=67.1676002&vertical=restaurants
Please modify this. It's working fine.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from selenium import webdriver

url= "https://www.foodpanda.pk/restaurants/new?lat=24.9414896&lng=67.1676002&vertical=restaurants"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:/chromedriver',options=options)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver.get(url)
panda =[]


[print(name.text) for name in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    ".vendor-list .headline .name")]
[print(expectetime.text) for expectetime in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    ".badge-info")]
try:
    [print(dealtag.text) for dealtag in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
        ".tag-container .multi-tag ")]
except:
    dealtag=''
try:
    [print(rating.text) for rating in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
        ".rating")]
except:
    rating=''

foodpanda={
    'Shop_name':name,
    'delivery_time': expectetime,
    'Deal_tag':dealtag,
    'Rating':rating

}
panda.append(foodpanda)
df = pd.DataFrame(panda)
print(df.head())
df.to_csv('foodpanda.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.foodpanda.pk/restaurants/new?lat=24.9414896&lng=67.1676002&vertical=restaurants")


# response = scrapy.Selector(text=driver.page_source)
list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.vendor-list li")
length = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.vendor-list li"))
for i in range(length):
    try:
        name = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".headline .name")[i].text
        time = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".badge-info")[i].text.strip()
        rating = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".rating")[i].text
        dealtag = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".multi-tag")[i].text
    except:
        pass
    print(name,time,rating,dealtag)
```